# White background when setting the plot background

Tags: matplotlib, shapely, cartopy

The following creates a plot with a white background thereby ignoring set_facecolor.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from descartes.patch import PolygonPatch
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.set_facecolor((198/255, 236/255, 253/255))
plt.show()
```

If I remove where I set the projection, then the color is as expected. How can I set the background color?

I am plotting my own map using shapely polygons using ax.plot. I wish to set the color of the water by setting the background color since my polygons have holes for representing lakes.

Answer (score 4):

Cartopy's projections create various new properties, including two extra patches, the background and outline patches.

It is likely that the background is the one you want to change, but without further example steps this is not certain. Here is how to set each one:

```
fig = plt.figure(); 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121,  projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,  projection=ccrs.Mercator())

ax1.background_patch.set_facecolor((198/255, 236/255, 253/255))
ax2.outline_patch.set_facecolor((198/255., 236/255., 253/255.))

plt.show()
```

[image: cartopy set properties]

Also take care with your color commands -- the example you gave used integer divide, which results in (0,0,0) = black.  On the 2nd suplot you see the color you presumably wanted.

For completeness, note that the regular axis patch is turned off, so changes to that patch will not be seen.